# How to access Zendesk APIs when authenticated by SAML from OKTA?

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, zendesk, okta-api, zendesk-api

I'm Using OKTA for Authenticating my users. Zendesk is one of the application connected to my OKTA user base, So, Once I log into my application (custom React JS based)  by OKTA, I can directly jump to Zendesk (as a logged in user). Is there any ways to use Zendesk APIs when I'm Authenticated by SAML from OKTA? What tokens will I use if I want to use Zendesk APIs and from where am I going to get them?

Note: I do get an access token and an id token on a okta success login, But I'm not sure these tokens can help me in anyway for using Zendesk API.

Thanks in Advance.  :)